# Time of arrival

Tags: php, time, gmt

```
New-York: GMT - 5
Chicago: GMT - 6

Time of departure: 07:00 (New-York time); travel time: 02:48.
```

How do I know at what time I'll be in Chicago? (Chicago time)

I'm sorry that I could not give its decision. Thanks.

Comment: depart time + travel time + TZ difference

Comment: do you store the date as well ? since just by looking at time on one time zone may not give actual time in another zone

Comment: Please get into the habit of using titles that give some clue as to the content of the question: "How to add datetimes in MySQL?" might be better.

Comment: Look at the [DateTimeZone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) class.

Comment: It's depart time + travel time+TZdifference(destination-source)

Comment: I know that the question's tagged with `PHP`, but is there an actual code question here? If there's some code where you're attempting to do this, then you should include it in your question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a combination of `DateTime()`, `DateInterval()`, and `DateTimeZone()`:

```
$flight = new DateTime('07:00', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$flight->add(new DateInterval('PT2H48M'));
$flight->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));
echo $flight->format('h:iA');
```

1. Create a `DateTime()` object representing the departure time in New York's timezone
2. Add 2 hours and 48 minutes of flight time
3. Change the timezone to Chicago's timezone
4. Print out the arrival time

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/EiwBLR)

Answer (score 0):

```
Time of Arrival (chicago TIme) = Time of departure(New-York time) + travel time: 02:48 + (New-York: GMT + Chicago: GMT)(in hours)
```